# Nginx controller service name wrongly configured

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an nginx ingress with multiple domain definitions. But nginx ingress is wrongly configuring the service name. I have open an issue https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3940 with the info.

Is an actual bug? Or I'm missing something.

Comment: Do I understand right that the service name is in both cases `x` instead of being in one of the cases `y`? If so, indeed that looks incorrect to me. Not sure to what extent did you modify the configs to hide real hostnames, because it seems they are present in the nginx.conf comments. Please double-check if there was no typo while obscuring the hostnames and service names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer for those who will face with the same in the future.
Issue described by @bitgandtter was fixed in [ing.Service with multiple hosts fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/3864) pull request. Fix will be included in the next version in couple of weeks. And before this time you can try to use dev image

```
quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:dev
```